# PHP 5.5 implementou a funcionalidade de foreach com list. Qual são os benefícios disso?

Tags: php

No PHP 5.5, temos uma funcionalidade nova, que é de usar `list` juntamente com o `foreach`.

```
$array = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
];

foreach ($array as list($a, $b)) {
    echo "A: $a; B: $b\n";
}
```

Saída é:

```
A: 1; B: 2
A: 3; B: 4
```

Eu entendi muito bem o que acontece na chama desse `foreach`, mas gostaria de saber como é que isso pode trazer benefícios na "vida real da programação", pois os exemplos do Manual do PHP são sempre simples de mais.

Quais são os benefícios trazidos ao podermos realizar um `foreach` com `list`?  Gostaria de alguns exemplos para fixar a ideia.

Answer (score 2):

A vantagem é que não há necessidade de se criar variáveis de índice e recuperar cada elemento do array utilizando essas variáveis. Tudo lhe é fornecido de forma simples e mais compacta. Basicamente o código fica mais simples. Note também que a tarefa de se utilizar índices acessar o array é repetitiva e não agrega nada pois sempre é feito a mesma coisa para loops. Logo, um constructo (foreach) que retira essa tarefa rotineira sem utilidade se torna interessante.

É verdade que isso não muda a maneira de programar, mas você vai notar que escrever código de loop sem a necessidade de se criar índices e instanciá-los é bem agradável, já que tal tarefa é repetitiva e não agrega nada ao código, como dito anteriormente.

Minha sugestão é: use esse constructo algumas vezes e depois forme uma opinião. Garanto que você vai gostar :).

Answer (score 1):

Penso que a ideia é para coisa mais "estranhas" como:

```
foreach ($array as list($a, $b, list($c, $d))) {
    echo "A: $a; B: $b; C: $c; D: $d;<br>";
};
```

Por vezes um foreach consegue fazer o trabalho todo...

Mas quanto a tua pergunta.. eu acho que é mais ir de encontra ao que as outras linguagens permitem..
Em termos práticos eu acho que nunca vou usar, e assim de repente nem vejo uma utilidade pratica..